# Angular 1.0 to Angular 1.6 [ERROR]

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I tried to put this(https://jsfiddle.net/j7rqgsf1/) jsfiddle code inside but I realised that i can not put on my project because of the versions.

Finally, when I replace the script, appears and ERROR:

controller:ctrlreg

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>
```

instead of

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.1/angular.min.js"></script>
```

Here is my controller file (controller.js)
[UPDATE app.js]

```
var app = angular.module('myModule',[]);
app.controller('ListaComprasController',function($scope){

        $scope.form = true;
        $scope.item = {};

        $scope.itens = [
            {nombre: 'Leite', telefono: 212122, descripcion: "tadsasasdas",especialidades:"tarea",dirreccion:"Siempre Viva 920",horarioDesde:"19:00",horarioHasta:"22:00",nombreCom:"Tssa",telefonoCom:"223123",checkCom:true,emailCom:"tesr@sdasad.com"},
            {nombre: 'Adssad', telefono: 3410220, descripcion: "tadsasasdas",especialidades:"tarea",dirreccion:"Siempre Viva 920",horarioDesde:"19:00",horarioHasta:"22:00",nombreCom:"Tssa",telefonoCom:"223123",checkCom:false,emailCom:"tesr@sdasad.com"}
        ];

        $scope.adicionaItem = function () {
            $scope.itens.push(
                {
                    nombre: $scope.item.nombre, 
                    telefono: $scope.item.telefono, 
                    descripcion: $scope.item.descripcion,
                    especialidades: $scope.item.especialidades,
                    dirreccion: $scope.item.dirreccion,
                    horarioDesde: $scope.item.horarioDesde,
                    horarioHasta: $scope.item.horarioHasta,
                    checkCom: $scope.item.checkCom,
                    nombreCom: $scope.item.nombreCom,
                    apellidoCom: $scope.item.apellidoCom,
                    telefonoCom: $scope.item.telefonoCom,
                    emailCom: $scope.item.emailCom
                }
            );
            $scope.item.produto = $scope.item.quantidade = '';
            toastr.success("Item adicionado com sucesso.");
            $scope.form = true;
        };
        $scope.addItem = function () {
            $scope.form = false;
        };
        $scope.editarItem = function(index){
            $scope.form = false;
            $scope.item = $scope.itens[index];
            $scope.edit = true;
        };

        $scope.applyChanges = function(index){
            $scope.item = {};
            $scope.form = false;
            $scope.edit = false;
            toastr.success("Item alterado com sucesso.");
        };
        $scope.CancelarItem = function(index){
            $scope.item.produto = $scope.item.quantidade = '';
            $scope.form = true;
        };
        $scope.deleteItem = function(index){
            $scope.itens.splice(index, 1);
            toastr.success("Item removido com sucesso.");
        };

});
```

Comment: What error you are getting?

Comment: @KalaikumarThangasamy Error: [$controller:ctrlreg] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.6.4/$controller/ctrlreg?p0=ListaComprasController

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using angular.js version above 1.3 , you need to declare the controller like this, Because global function declaration for controller supports only with angularjs 1.2 and below

```
var app = angular.module('myModule',[]);
app.controller('ListaComprasController',function($scope){
  ///
});
```

**[`DEMO`](https://jsfiddle.net/Lz74rhp2/)**

Comment: Sorry i tried that but still the same error...I have edited my post

Comment: you are missing angular.js reference and ng-app . here is the working fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/Lz74rhp2/

Comment: sorry same problem...what have u changed? i can make a github project

Comment: can i ask u a question on chat?